# SignalR + Redis Change Channel Suffix?

Tags: c#, redis, signalr

I have one redis cache that a worker writes to via channels.
In this case, imagine we have the `test` channel. All channels have a prefix of `dev::`.
I am using StackExchange.Redis for access.

Writing to redis works just fine. The issue comes when I try to use SignalR on my web application. Below is my setup:

```
services.AddSignalR(o => { o.EnableDetailedErrors = true; }).AddStackExchangeRedis(configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisConnection"), options =>
    {
        options.Configuration.DefaultDatabase = int.Parse(configuration["AppSettings:RedisDatabase"]);
        options.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = configuration["AppSettings:RedisPrefix"];
        options.Configuration.IncludeDetailInExceptions = true;
    });
```

Now this does correctly connect to redis. I can do the following:

```
hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("test", "HelloWorld");
```

and it will write to my redis cache. But I am expecting to see the channel of `dev::test`. Instead I see `dev::App.Web.Hubs.ExampleHub:all`. In addition, instead of seeing a simple string `HelloWorld` I see a json object.

Now, I could implement SignalR on the worker and have it write to the redis cache using this same method. The issue there is that the channel it writes to is `dev::Worker.Hubs.ExampleHub:all`. In this case it is writing to a totally different channel.

How would I go about making these two apps communicate correctly?

**The end goal**

I wish to have my worker write to redis. Then I want my web application to see the change and alert all of the clients of this change using SignalR.

Note: I am fine writing to a table as well, but I was having trouble finding a way to bind the redis table to SignalR.

Comment: Are you already using redis and are trying to relay changes to your web apps?

Comment: @davidfowl Yes. But we want to use SignalR to relay those changes to the browser. I have found a way to do this, but not using Redis as a backplane. I had to make another services and link Redis pub/sub with SignalR hubs.

Comment: That sounds good for this scenario! Bare in mind that if you want cross instance communication when using SignalR primitives (like groups) then you'll need to explicitly tell SignalR to use redis as well. Otherwise you can do that yourself by sending messages through redis, and then sending messages on each subscriber (node/machine/process) via signalr.

Comment: Yea thanks! I figured out how to communicate cross instance, I was hoping SignalR would let me change the channel prefix it was using so I could have it communicate across instances and applications. But it looks like that option is not available yet.